# Dojo - Adding dijit to a closed TitlePane

Tags: javascript, dojo

When the open property of TitlePane is set to false, I can't add an widgets dynamically to the content.

For example, the following code does not work.

```
var tp = new dijit.TitlePane({
   title: "Title Pane"
   , content: ""
   , open: false
})

var tabs = new dijit.layout.TabContainer({
   region:"center"
   , content:"Service Details"
   , tabStrip: true
}).placeAt(tp.containerNode);
```

But when the open property is set to true, the tab container appears.

```
var tp = new dijit.TitlePane({
   title: "Title Pane"
   , content: ""
   , open: true
})

var tabs = new dijit.layout.TabContainer({
   region:"center"
   , content:"Service Details"
   , tabStrip: true
}).placeAt(tp.containerNode);
```

How can I add widgets to a TitlePane when the open property set to false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're calling `startup` properly on your programmatically-created widgets?  The following works for me whether `open` is `true` or `false`:

```
dojo.require('dijit.TitlePane');
dojo.require('dijit.layout.TabContainer');
dojo.require('dijit.layout.ContentPane');
dojo.ready(function() {
    var tp = new dijit.TitlePane({
        title: "Title Pane",
        content: "",
        open: false
    }).placeAt(dojo.body());


    var tabs = new dijit.layout.TabContainer({
        region: "center",
        content: "Service Details",
        tabStrip: true
    }).placeAt(tp.containerNode);
    tabs.startup();
    tabs.addChild(new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
        title: 'foo', content: 'bar'
    }));

    //putting this after adding the tabcontainer
    //avoids problems when open is initially true
    tp.startup();
});
```

To clarify on calling `startup`:

Generally, any time you programatically create a widget, you need to manually call its `startup`.  However...

The general exception to this is when dealing with children of container or layout widgets (in this case `dijit.TitlePane` which extends `dijit.layout.ContentPane`, which behaves like a layout widget) - these look for children to call `startup` on when they are started themselves (or in the case of `ContentPane`, also when new content is set/loaded).

Container widgets (not `ContentPane`, but e.g. `BorderContainer`, `StackContainer` and its subclasses such as `AccordionContainer` and `TabContainer`) also call `startup` on children added after the container is already started.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that the order that startup() was  called affected anything. When is an explicit startup() call required and when should it be called? Is there a good technique or a dojo utility that would help assure that the startup() calls order is correct and that they're not called more often than needed?

Comment: After experimenting a little, I've found that a startup() call is needed for each Container but not each Pane and that the call should happen immediately after all the content has been inserted into given Container. Is this a good assumption?

Comment: Post edited to clarify calling of `startup`, see portion after code block.

Comment: thx i was scratching my head over this.... this is my code i had to init the titlepane first then the datagrid..`var dijitTitle = new dijit.TitlePane({
                        title: baseLayout.tableTitle,
                        open:index==0?true:false
                    },creationDivTitle);
                    fisaSubGrid = new FisaSubGrid(subGridParams);
                    dijitTitle.startup();
                    dijitTitle.addChild(fisaSubGrid);
                    fisaSubGrid.startup();`